# JAXP: How to validate a org.w3c.dom.Document against a XML Schema

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, jaxp

How to validate an (already parsed) `org.w3c.dom.Document` against a XML Schema using JAXP?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [javax.xml.validation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html) APIs for this.

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
URL schemaURL = // The URL to your XML Schema; 
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaURL); 
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDOM);
validator.validate(source);
```

The example below demonstrates how to validate a JAXB object model against a schema, but you'll see it's easy to replace the JAXBSource with a DOMSource for DOM:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Comment: Thank you Blaise. Although not directly related to the question, I'd like to ask you another one: What if a specified Schema (which has been passed by a StreamSource to the SchemaFactory) includes another schema which is available only as a ClassLoader resource? Passing two StreamSource's didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @MRalwasser - see `SchemaFactory.setResourceResolver`.  there is all kinds of great information in the javadocs...

Comment: @jtahlbborn: thank you, this worked. But: It seems that when validating a Document that way that the schema's default values are not respected, the Document and its nodes remain untouched.

Comment: @MRalwasser - To have the DOM affected by the schema, you need to set the schema on the DocumentBuilderFactory used to create the parser, before parsing the XML to a DOM.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do only know the schema location after the xml has been parsed (or is there something like a ResourceResolver/EntityResolver for the root schema defined in a xml? Because I'd like to pass a classloader resource stream)